# send get request to specific file

Tags: laravel, routes

I have a file called: `test.php` located in `public/inc/test.php`. Through jQuery, I can make a get request through jQuery ($.get)`, by typing:`URL: "public/inc/test.php?" + param1` etc.

I want to do the same, but through Laravel. I want to have a route called: `/sendparams/{param1}/{param2}`, and do a get request to the `test.php` file from inside a route in `web.php` and pass the params variables.

How should the route be written?

edit:

by implementing the classes in laravel as external classes, this is no more needed.

Answer (score 0):

you have in your laravel project a file named web.php inside the routes folder.
Define within the web.php file the below code:

```
Route::get('/sendparams/{param1}/{param2}', 'ControllerName@index');
```

Perform the below command to create the controller

```
php artisan make:controller ControllerName
```

Open ControllerName (app/Http/Controllers/ControllerName)

Your new controller has an structure like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class MailController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
    }
    /* This is the method executed in your route defined in web.php*/
    public function index(Request $request) {
         $param1 = $request->param1;
         $param2 = $request->param2;
         $allParams = $request->all();  // returns an associative array with all params

    }
}
```

you can check your routes performed the below command

```
php artisan route:list
```

Regards